# Getting 2.2204460492503E-16 in php Subtraction

Tags: php

$diff = $choice->GetAmount() - $choice->GetPrice();

If the input for both is equal i.e 1.25 and 1.25 it shows 2.2204460492503E-16 instead of 0

Comment: When working with finances, work in cents, not dollars. Avoids floating point math.

Comment: _Integer_ values of cents. Never floats. There are libraries that help you deal with money without losing or duplicating pennies. eg: http://moneyphp.org/